# setting string and looping through lines in a .txt file to a JLabel with java

Tags: java, string, filereader

I have a program that should read lines from `upload.txt`

Then each line should be posted to a `JLabel` cycling through the lines in `upload.txt` on click of a `JButton`

I have not ran the program yet because I am getting an error here `file(textile);` 
This line is in the main method before the program closes.

My question is how can I fix this error and does the way my code is set up effectively accomplish my goal?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver {
    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;
    private int clicked;

    public Driver() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");
        p = new JPanel();

        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);

        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();

        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500, 400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")) {
                    jl.setText(problems());
                    b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                } else {
                    jl.setText(problems());
                    b = "Click For Answer";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
            }
        });

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (clicked++ == 10) {
                    Object[] options = { "No, thanks", "Yes, please" };

                    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                       "Would you like more math questions? ",
                       "Math Questions", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                       options[1]);

                    if (response == 1)
                       clicked = 1; // reset
                    else
                       System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public String problems() {
        File file = new File("upload.txt");

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i);
            }

            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return problems();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Driver();
                Scanner textfile = null;

                try {
                    textfile = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                problems(textfile);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the syntax as you have it says to call a function named file passing in to it the Scanner instance. Where is the method "file" defined?

Comment: What method do you think `file(textfile)` is going to run?

Comment: im sorry I meant that to be problems. problems is the method scanning.

Comment: i edited it. sorry about that. I know I am close to solving this. This is my first time using a scanner to read a file.

Comment: @NichoDiaz the method "problems" in the driver class does not take in any parameters so you have to fix that first. Second, you are not saving the Driver instance you create into a variable (Driver myDriver = new Driver(); myDriver.problems(textfile); is about what you need to change). Third, check your return statement in the problems method. right now you have infinite recursion (the method will call itself endlessly) so figure out exactly what you want it to return before running it.

Comment: like this?  public String problems(String problems)???

Comment: Also, you are returning a call to `problems()` at the end of `problems()`.  This is going to recurse forever until you run out of stack.

Comment: ok so my error is in the method problems? It needs to take parameters  public String problems(String problems) <-- like that? I remove the return and I get errors here  public String problems(String problems)

Comment: @NichoDiaz No, because the type of textfile is a Scanner instance so it has to be public String problems(Scanner fileScanner). If you want to return a String from this method then you have to create a String in that method presumably made up of the integers you read from the file, but that is up to you, just return a String instance to remove the compile error.

Comment: You have several errors caused by basic misconceptions about the way java works.

Comment: What is the point of saying "You have several errors caused by basic misconceptions about the way java works. " Was that supposed to be constructive criticism? If so would you mind adding the constructive part so its not just a waste of time reading your condescending comments that provide no helpful feedback?

Comment: My point was to suggest that you go read a basic java tutorial, so that you understand how to invoke a method on an object, and how return types work.

Comment: @ Steven Magana-Zook Thank you for being so helpful. I changed the method problems to return a string called s. so in order to have it grab each line should something like this work?  String s = scanner.nextLine(); then return s? will this just return each line when the method is invoked? so if I add  jl.setText(s); onclick of the JButton this should be fine?